# Whats the overrall power available from two PSUs in series?

Tags: power-supply, power, series

Consider this circuit:

[image]

PSU 1 is rated at 100w, PSU 2 is rated at 200w.

How do I calculate how much power is available to the load, given the mis-matched power supplies?

Comment: You would treat it just like batteries in series. The lowest capacity battery sets you maximum power or current or capacity.

Comment: @vini_i You can treat them like batteries in series if the supplies have isolated outputs, but I would not _assume_ that the outputs are isolated.  What happens if there is a hidden connection between the (-) outputs of both supplies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The maximum current you can draw is the value of the lowest one.

In this case the 100W supply could provide 8.3A, while the 200W supply could provide twice that at 16.6Amps.  If you attempted to extract more than 8.3A the lower capability power supply would collapse (and possibly damage it). So the output is limited by the smaller supply to 8.3A @24V, 200W.

If you put supplies in series it is often desirable to put a diode across each supply so that under overload conditions the output polarity does not reverse.  The diode should be able to pass the current of the highest output supply.  The diode polarity should be such that under normal conditions it is reverse biased.

A similar arrangement is used with photovoltaic solar arrays to avoid reverse biasing modules if one gets shaded.

Comment: Great, thanks... another related question: would the current be divided across the PSUs just like the voltage? So if the load was 150w, it would draw 6.25A, with each PSU providing 3.125A? Meaning PSU1 would be 37.5% loaded, and PSU2 18.75% loaded?

Comment: No, since the PSUs re in series they will see the same current.  That is why the lower power supply sets the maximum output current.  Since they are the same voltage they will provide the same power, even though one of them could provide much more.

Comment: What if they were in parallel?

Comment: It is difficult to get parallel supplies to share the load.  The one that is higher voltage (even if it is only 1/10th of  volt) will take all the load. Two supplies will never have exactly the same voltage.

Comment: @KevinWhite: An accurate description of the problem, but it's not entirely correct to say that load balancing is completely impossible.  It's possible to arrange the feedback that governs the voltage regulation to respond not only to the individual supply's output voltage but also the current distribution between supplies.  Use of multichannel feedback will achieve synchronization of output voltage from all supplies.